# When image size change, how do you calculate to counter the real-size coordinate value?

Tags: c#, image, unity-game-engine, coordinates

I want to know the coordinates value when the image is stretched from the center.

I know one pixel coordinate in texture image, and I'm using ray cast by matching it to mobile screen.

But I don't know how the coordinate value changes when the image grows.

[image]

When images grow, how do you calculate to counter the real-size coordinate value?

The image will increase to 1.33f size.

[image]

Comment: `real size coordinates` in what? Screenspace pixels/centimeters? WorldSpace 3d coordinates?

Comment: @derHugo real size coordinate is Screenspace pixel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be simpler ways in Unity3D - I don't have any experience there - but this sounds like a fairly simple scaling problem.

You'll need to know the following:

- The image coordinates of the centre of the image
  This is the vector `(width/2, height/2)`
- The screen coordinates of the centre of the image
  Where the center of the image is on the screen
- The scaling factor (`1.33f` in this example)

Given the above you can calculate the pixel being touched using simple math:

```
public Vector2Int ScaleTouch(Vector2Int imgCentre, Vector2Int dispCentre, float scale, Vector2Int touch)
{
    var x = imgCentre.x + (touch.x - dispCentre.x) * scale;
    var y = imgCentre.y + (touch.y - dispCentre.y) * scale;
    return Vector2Int.RoundToInt(new Vector2(x, y));
}
```

Or using the methods in `Vector2` and `Vector2Int` you might be able to do this:

```
public Vector2Int ScaleTouch(Vector2Int imgCentre, Vector2Int dispCentre, float scale, Vector2Int touch)
{
    var offset = Vector2.Scale(touch - dispCentre, new Vector2(scale, scale));
    return offset + imgCentre;
}
```

Both assume that your scale is homogeneous in `x` and `y`.  You could provide a scale vector if you want it to be flexible about scaling in different axes.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Is the ImgCenter a bigger image? Or is it the original image?

Comment: I think, var x = imgCenter.x + (touch.x - imgCenter.x) * scale, This is working normally. Thank you